# Rename tag "souleater" to "soul-eater"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retagging

The title is two words so the tag should include the dash in place of where the space should be.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, this is the standard naming convention as stated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions/88003#88003).

> Replaces spaces with dashes (-) to combine multiple words into a single word (i.e, Tag "Unit Testing" as "unit-testing").